# Not able to Print output for "IF" methods using Global Variables

Tags: java

The Below code does not print values for "IF" methods alone.

Note: I have used Global variables.If i use it as local variables i am able to print values for all the methods

Currently output is not displayed for `Oddif(10)` and `evenIF(10)`

```
public class even {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        even o = new even();
        o.evenFor(10);
        o.evenWhile(10);
        o.evenIf(10);
        o.OddFor(10);
        o.OddWhile(10);
        o.OddIf(10);
    }

    public void evenFor(int n) {

        System.out.print("The Even Numbers using For Loop are:" + " ");
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i = i + 2) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    public void evenWhile(int n) {
        System.out.print("The Even Numbers using while loop are:" + " ");
        while (i <= n) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");

            i = i + 2;
        }

        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    public void evenIf(int n) {

        System.out.print("The Even Numbers using if loop:" + " ");
        while (i <= n) {
            if (i <= n) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");

                i = i + 2;
            }

        }

        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    public void OddIf(int n) {

        System.out.print("The Odd Numbers using if loop:" + " ");
        while (j <= n) {

            if (j <= n) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");

                j = j + 2;
            }

        }

        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    public void OddFor(int n) {
        System.out.print("The Odd Numbers using For Loop are:" + " ");
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 2) {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }

        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    public void OddWhile(int n) {

        System.out.print("The Odd Numbers using while loop are:" + " ");
        while (j <= n) {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
            enter code here j = j + 2;
        }

        System.out.print("\n");
    }

}
```

Actual Output:

```
    The Even Numbers using For Loop are: 0 2 4 6 8 10 
    The Even Numbers using while loop are: 0 2 4 6 8 10 
    The Even Numbers using if loop: 
    The Odd Numbers using For Loop are: 1 3 5 7 9 
    The Odd Numbers using while loop are: 1 3 5 7 9 
    The Odd Numbers using if loop:
```

Comment: Your problem is using global variables.

Comment: Yes.I want the output for IF methods using global variables?can you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using global variable, whenever you are changing it in the methods, it is preserving the changed value. And this is one of the reason that we use global variable.

So, better make them local variables. But if you insist on keeping them as global variable, make a copy of the variables in each method and work on it. That's how the global variables will remain unchanged.

For example:

```
public void evenWhile(int n)
{
    int temp = i; // taking a copy of global variable
    System.out.print("The Even Numbers using while loop are:" + " ");
    while(temp <=n)
    {
        System.out.print(temp +" ");    
        temp += 2; // changing the local copy, not the global which we need unchanged
    }    
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: It worked fine for while and for methods.how come if methods are not working?Can you suggest?

Comment: should work as the global variables are not being changed. Recheck the logic of these 'if' methods. And again, why are you checking the condition in `if`, where you have already checked the same condition in `while` before it? Isn't it redundant?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after the program runs through

```
OddFor(){}
```

It will leave j = 11. That's why when you try to run

```
OddWhile(){}
```

The program will just skip the loop because j is already greater than 10.
So at the end of each method you could set the value of the i/j back to the value you started from.

Comment: Thanks Much appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

In the 'If' method, you have a condition if(i < n). This condition is not satisfied.
This is because i = n = 10. i was set as 10 in the evenWhile method.